# Middleware in Node.js with OO JavaScript

Tags: node.js, openshift, passport.js

Currently I am trying to use the middleware "passport" in an object oriented Node.js server. After restarting the server everything works fine. I can access the route where no authentication is required. But when I am trying to access a route with authentication I always get the response 401 (No-Authentication). This seems to be ok but unfortunately I do not enter the function(username, password, done) in the LocalStrategy.

So I think my problem is in the way I try to use a middleware in the oo javascript style. The template I used to start is from the RedHat OpenShift Cloud and can be seen in: https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-custom-version-openshift/blob/master/server.js

Here is my server initialization method where I tried to use the passport middleware:

```
self.initializeServer = function() {

    self.createGetRoutes();
    self.createPostRoutes();

    self.app = express.create();

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            console.log("TEST");

            process.nextTick(function () {
                console.log('Here I am!');
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));

    self.app.configure(function() {
        self.app.use(passport.initialize());
    });

    // Paths without authentication
    self.app.get('/holy', function(req, res) {res.send('SHIT! \n')});

    //  Add GET handlers for the app with authentication (from the getRoutes).
    for (var g in self.getRoutes) {
        self.app.get(g, passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }), self.getRoutes[g]);
    }

    // Add POST handlers for the app with authentication (from the postRoutes).
    for (var p in self.postRoutes) {
        self.app.post(p, passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }), self.postRoutes[p]);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that you don't use the right strategy. You should use the BasicStrategy to use the http authentication: [Passport-HTTP](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http)

Comment: Thank you, you are right this is the strategy I want to use. Finally you also brought me to the right way. I was searching for the constructor of passport. I thought I can simply use self.passport = new Passport() or self.passport = passport(). (Like the way express is allowing it). After examining the passport implementation I found out I have to use self.passport = new passport.Passport();

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are not using the `express.router()` middleware.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. Just added the express.router configuration but the method still is not called. Normally I expect a log message (console.log("TEST");) if a user is trying to access an site where authentication is required. In my opinion the problem must be in the usage of passport in a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [http-auth](http://http-auth.info) for HTTP Basic/Digest authentication:

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```

or you can use it with [passport](http://passportjs.org):

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Application setup.
var app = express();

// Setup strategy.
var passport = require('passport');
passport.use(auth.passport(basic));

// Setup route.
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('http', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
});
```